# iphone storyboard tab bar controller become fat

Tags: iphone

I have a problem that my iphone project, my storyboard `Tab Bar Controller`, become different, like the picture.

When i delete the tab bar controller connect and reconnect that become normal, and i save the project, but when i open it, tab bar controller become different, how could i solve the problem, thanks!

[image]

The status bar is disappear, when the `Tab Bar Controller` become fat.

Comment: It's not "fat", it's in landscape mode.